# Does weapon weight count in World of Tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I'm driving a Luchs (Light Tank) as a scout in WoT and I'm having a problem about choosing between the main gun:

- Gun 3cm M.K. 103
- Gun 5cm Kw.K. 39 L/60

The latteris better in every aspect (apart from burst damage) but it weights **700kg** while the former is just **141kg**. Does this count in WoT? For example does using the latter makes my tank accelerate significantly faster?

I'm not looking for acceleration-based information it was just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not been able to found numbers on a ratio of weight vs acceleration difference.

According to this [World of tanks forum post](http://forum.worldoftanks.com/index.php?/topic/53842-weight-speed-acceleration-for-scouts/) (last answer), weight affects your acceleration and hill climbing ability.

> Top speed, acceleration, and turn rate.  Top speed appears to be fixed per vehicle.  Acceleration (and hill climbing speed) are based on power/weight ratio.  More powerful engines increase acceleration and hill climbing, more weight (from modules or equipment) decreases it.
>
> Tracks change your turn rate and up your weight capacity.  Grousers, torsion bars, etc bump your wight capacity.  The more of that extra weight capacity you use, the slower you will accelerate or climb hills.  Better drivers/commanders/vents bring all 3 closer to their stated 'perfect' stat.

Also stated [in this thread, first answer](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/40207-suspension-weight-limit-and-speed/)

> a) Weight does affect acceleration but top speed is fixed. Weight limit has no effect on acceleration.

Also further in that thread :

> And yes, a tank without equipment will accelerate faster. Although a one ton spall liner makes a much bigger difference on a 15 ton tank than it does on one that's 100 tons. I've found about 5% extra weight is noticeable and 10% and easily noticeable so most of the time equipment doesn't make much difference.

So for your case with the [Luch](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Tank:PzII_Luchs), you should notice a difference in acceleration with the lighter gun since the tank is a light one.

Also, note that the wiki states

> Once upgraded, the Luchs gains incredibly high acceleration, the ability to turn on a dime often causing it drift when turning at high speeds.

With the best engine, you might still notice the difference but the pros of having a upgraded gun might be worth more than the increase in acceleration since the top speed will remain the same. Rare are the maps where you should not be able to reach near top speed before encountering enemies.

You'll need to try what fits your playstyle best but for the information available, if you have the best engine, you should get the bigger gun and use half a load of ammo to reduce some weight, remove any equipment that are not needed for your scouting/playstyle and still be able to dish some damage while scouting efficiently.

Comment: I haven't played in quite some time, but heavier cannons also made your turret rotate slower, IIRC.

Comment: Yes but since the question was about acceleration, I decided to focus on that.

Comment: Acceleration was just an example. I'm interested in every aspect.

Comment: @AdamArold What else you wish to know? Weight only affects how the tank accelerates and handle. In your specific case, the best gun should be matched with the best engine so not to lose too much acceleration. With the best turret, you might not lose too much speed turning it.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I was not aware that ammo has a weight as well :)

Comment: Well, the "don't take a whole load of ammo" advice is more about the ammo rack having less chance to explode if not full. And as usually a scout tank role is all about not being seen, thus not firing... A full rack is just the best way to get instantly destroyed should you get spotted.

Answer (score 0):

The weight affects many things, including speed/acceleration, and also what you can equip. Your tracks have a weight load limit, say 1500 Kg (not a real number, just for example). With the 700 Kg gun, you can only have 800 more Kg, and might not be able to equip a new radio because it adds too much weight. Weight is something to be mindful of, but not the most important factor when choosing weapons.